# Primefaces selectOneMenu blocks method call in Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem when i use the following drop down list in my page. In detail , when i use the **selectOneMenu**  and press on the button listed below the method **save** is never called. It just goes through the all the methods i have defined with an f:event only.  Once i remove the **selectOneMenu** from my page and press the save button again, my method is called without any problem.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="unitList"
    value="#{myController.userDTO.selectedUnitDTO}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myController.unitList}" var="unitList"
        itemValue="#{unitList}" itemLabel="#{unitList.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The drop down list data is loaded by the following method (Note.  unitList is initialiazed)

```
public List<UnitDTO> getUnitList() {
    return unitList;
}
```

My bean has following annotations **@ManagedBean @ViewScoped**

and  this is my button:

```
<p:commandButton id="save" action="#{myController.save}" value="SAVE"  />
```

Further info, i have noticed that when i press the save button the setter of **selectedUnitDTO** is never called.

*Primefaces Version: 6.0*

Comment: Do you have a `Converter` for your `UnitDTO`? Seems like validation and/or conversion fail, so your setter never gets called.

Comment: No, i do not use a converter. The object type that is retrieved from unitList is the same as the selectedUnitDTO i want to set.

Comment: Put an `h:messages` in your page and you'll most likely see an error (most likely in the log as well). You **need** a converter in this case. The itemValue is a String when it is posted back to the server, not an object. Try with a plain jsf selectOneMenu, same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF require converters when you use objects, in this case, for `p:selectonemenu`

You can add the next java class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("converterUnitDTO")
public class ConverterUnitDTO implements Converter {

    @Override
    public UnitDTO getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        List<UnitDTO> unitsDTO = (List<UnitDTO>) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{myController.unitList}", List.class);
        for (UnitDTO unitDTO : unitsDTO)
            if (unitDTO.toString().equals(value))
                return unitDTO;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        try {
            return value.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

In your xhtml change to this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="unitList"
    value="#{myController.userDTO.selectedUnitDTO}" converter="converterUnitDTO">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myController.unitList}" var="unitList"
        itemValue="#{unitList}" itemLabel="#{unitList.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. I needed a converter. I did it sort of different though to match my needs. Instead of retrieving with (List<UnitDTO>) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{myController.unitList}", List.class); and iterating, i create a new UnitDTO set the id and return the newly created UnitDTO. Thank you.